# Return email address of recipient

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm building a macro that will run automatically when I move into the body of an email to check the email address of the recipient.

I cannot get the address of the recipient to load into a variable.

```
Sub BuildTable()
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myRecipient As String
Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipient.Address
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are running in MS Outlook and in an Active Inspector, so perhaps:

```
Sub CheckAddresses()
Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim r As Recipient
Dim rList As Recipients

Set oEmail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

Set rList = oEmail.Recipients
rList.ResolveAll
For Each r In rList
    Debug.Print r.Address
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, also.  I got this method to work as well, with a slight repurposing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of Outlook you are using, but according to Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211006(v=office.11).aspx) you need to use the .Recipients(Index) to get a Recipient.  From there you may be able to get the address.  I also saw mention of some sort of ResolveAll method attached to .Recipients, though that referenced Outlook 2000 (eww).

Try doing

```
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myRecipient as String
Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Item(0).Address
```

This will give you the address of the first recipient (note I can't remember if VBA starts at index 0 or 1, if you get IndexOutOfRange, change to 1).  If you need others, you're going to need to do a loop.  Something like this:

```
For Each Recipient in myItem.Recipients
// do some stuff here
Next Recipient
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I'm using 2010.

I think what is throwing me off is that they're instructing me to create a new item instead of simply accessing the value that is in the mailitem.  I'm just lost at this point how to get these values (sorry, I really only dabble in Coldfusion/SQL Server).

I appreciate the help.

-ZL

Comment: I don't use Outlook for VBA, only Excel.  Hold on and I'll try and figure it out for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I got it to work.  I appreciate your time and attention.

Answer (score 0):

This is what this segment of code ended up looking like:

```
Sub BuildTable1()

Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem

Set oEmail = Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Application.Visible = True
xlApp.workbooks.Open FileName:= file location

xlApp.WorkSheets("Contacts").Activate
xlApp.Range("A6").Value = oEmail.To


//filtering by value, copying, pasting, etc.
End Sub
```

-ZL