# Get Alias Address From Outlook.Recipients

Tags: vba, outlook

We use Office 365 Outlook Exchange.

We have different customer related email mailboxes, which have their own separate accounts.
For example support@google.com, sales@google.com, and customerservice@google.com etc.
To save on costs an idea came up that instead of paying for different customer related accounts that we create an email alias for each of them in a single account e.g. tasks@google.com.

The problem is that the Outlook.Recipient email address shows tasks@google.com.
This does not tell me who the customer was trying to email. I need to know which alias the customer was trying to email.

Here is code that I am using to try to extract the alias.
It is returning the account email i.e. tasks@google.com instead of the alias.

```vb
Function GetEmailRecipient(mail As Outlook.MailItem) As String
    Dim Recips As Outlook.Recipients
    Dim Recip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim Pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Dim ToEmail As String
    
    Set Recips = mail.Recipients
    For Each Recip In Recips
        Set Pa = Recip.PropertyAccessor
        If ToEmail > "" Then
            ToEmail = ToEmail & ";" &Recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Alias
        Else
            ToEmail = Recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Alias
        End If
    Next
    GetEmailRecipient = ToEmail
End Function
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. I am one of your customers. On any given day, I might enquire about your Mark II widget, complain about the last invoice and seek help with one of my existing Mark I widgets. Currently, I must know your company structure and send each email to the correct department. In future I need not know your company structure. I just send all emails to tasks@google.com and your system decides which department will deal with which email. I do not understand what you think I typed instead of tasks@google.com that will help with that decision.

Comment: Do you only want to return email address of recipient?

If yes, you could refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656906/return-email-address-of-recipient

Comment: @TonyDallimore Sorry it was confusing, I rewrote the explantation.

Comment: I have a home installation so you have access to functionality that is unavailable to me. I can find very little documentation about `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Alias`. My interpretation of that documentation is that it is accessing information in your address book about people to whom you send emails. I cannot find anything to suggest that it can access information about the alias the sender of an email used for your address.

Comment: I have just noticed that the `Then` and `Else` code for `If ToEmail > ""` is the same.  I suspect the `Then` code should concatenate the new alias to previous aliases.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Yes, you are correct. I broke the code in my testing as I have been swapping different properties testing the values. I did not see that I overwrote my concatenation attempt. I have corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help.

Select a few of these emails and then run the following macro which will output the entire SMTP header for each selected email.

Note that the Immediate Window has a limit of about 200 lines. I normally output diagnostic information like this to a file. If you would like a copy of that version of the macro, I am happy to add it.

```
Sub OutHeader()

  Dim Exp As Outlook.Explorer
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem
  Dim PropAccess As Outlook.propertyAccessor

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  If Exp.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "No emails selected"
  Else
    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      With ItemCrnt
        Set PropAccess = .propertyAccessor
        Debug.Print "--------------"
        Debug.Print PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E")
      End With
    Next
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to code this out. However I am hoping my new explanation that I submitted will clarify what it is that I am having an issue with.

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs  An email consists of a header and a body. The body contains the text message plus any attachments. The header is plain text and identifies who the email is from, who the email is to, subject, details of each node between sender and receiver and much more. Some of this data is standard but some is unique to a single email package. If the alias information you seek is in the email, it must be in the header. This was why I suggested you look at the header. Once you know the alias information is in the header, you can investigate how to extract it.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct I was able to determine that the info is in the header. I can see it from Outlook in the email messages properties Unfortunately when I ran your code it returned: "X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics". After that the rest of the string looks like it has been hashed or something as was unreadable.

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs  Strange.  I have used that schema, and others, many times without problems.  That schema can be very useful in locating data that Outlook does not extract and place in one of it properties.  You might like to try my code on a different email to determine if that email was corrupt or if the code behind the schema is corrupt on your system.

Comment: It is strange. I have even tried CDO and it comes up empty. I wonder if it is a configuration issue or maybe a security setting?

Comment: Are you just looking at the first line of that property? That property is a multiline text blob.

Comment: Also keep in mind that Exchange always resolves the recipients to the internal EX type addresses, the original SMTP address is not stored in the recipient table.

Comment: I have found a number of posts about X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics-untrusted causing the header to exceed its maximum length which corrupts it.. For example: support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH246940.html

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs I forgot to add your name to the last post so you will not have been told about it. This is a known bug which the referenced article tells you how to avoid.

Comment: I got IT to try the Symantec solution you provided in the link. This is what ultimately cleared it up so that I can then read the headers. Once that was cleared your first answer was spot on and I was able to apply it! Now I just have to figure out the cleanest way to parse out the To: line but I should be able to do that with a little head scratching, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I was having @TonyDallimore helped me to resolve as the accepted answer above. However I still needed to retrieve the recipient property from the header. The following code is what I came up with in conjunction with Tony's code plus my own parse function. It parses the full email header out into an array.

```
Function GetEmailRecipient(msg As Outlook.MailItem) As String
    Dim Recips As Outlook.Recipients
    Dim Recip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim Pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Dim EmailHeader As String
    Dim HeaderProperties As Variant
    Dim Recepient As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set Pa = msg.PropertyAccessor
    EmailHeader = Pa.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E")
    ' Parse Header Into Array
    HeaderProperties = ParseEmailHeader(EmailHeader)
    ' Capture Recepient Email Value
    For i = LBound(HeaderProperties) To UBound(HeaderProperties)
            ' Array Index
            Debug.Print HeaderProperties(i, 0)
            ' Header Property Name
            Debug.Print HeaderProperties(i, 1)
            ' Header Property Value
            Debug.Print HeaderProperties(i, 2)
    Next
    GetEmailRecipient = Recepient
End Function

Private Function ParseEmailHeader(EmailHeader As String) As Variant
    Dim Delim As String
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim Arr2 As Variant
    Dim ArrRet As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim PropertyName As String
    Dim PropertyValue As String


    Delim = EmailHeader
    ' Add delimiters into header string
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "Received:", "~Received:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "Authentication-Results:", "~Authentication-Results:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "Content-Type:", "~Content-Type:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "Content-Transfer-Encoding:", "~Content-Transfer-Encoding:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "From:", "~From:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "To:", "~To:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "Subject:", "~Subject:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "Thread-Topic:", "~Thread-Topic:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "Thread-Index:", "~Thread-Index:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "Date:", "~Date:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "Message-ID:", "~Message-ID:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "Accept-Language:", "~Accept-Language:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "Content-Language:", "~Content-Language:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Has-Attach:", "~X-MS-Has-Attach:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Has-Attach:", "~X-MS-Has-Attach:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL:", "~X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:", "~X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "MIME-Version:", "~MIME-Version:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality:", "~X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource:", "~X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs:", "~X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism:", "~X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-Originating-IP:", "~X-Originating-IP:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-ID:", "~X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-ID:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-PublicTrafficType:", "~X-MS-PublicTrafficType:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:", "~X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-Antispam-SRFA-Diagnostics:", "~X-MS-Exchange-Antispam-SRFA-Diagnostics:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "Return-Path:", "~Return-Path:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime:", "~X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason:", "~X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval:", "~X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason:", "~X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id:", "~X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-Microsoft-Antispam:", "~X-Microsoft-Antispam:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic:", "~X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-Test:", "~X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-Test:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "UriScan:", "~UriScan:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test:", "~X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-Forefront-Antispam-Report:", "~X-Forefront-Antispam-Report:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "SpamDiagnosticOutput:", "~SpamDiagnosticOutput:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime:", "~X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader:", "~X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id:", "~X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id:", "~X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped:", "~X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency:", "~X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering:", "~X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:", "~X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:")
    Delim = Replace(Delim, "X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:", "~X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:")

    ' Split Header String Into Array
    Arr = Split(Delim, "~")
    ReDim ArrRet(0 To 58, 0 To 2)
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        If Arr(i) > "" Then
            ' Split Property Name/ Value
            Arr2 = Split(Arr(i), ":")
            PropertyName = Arr2(0)
            PropertyValue = Arr2(1)
            ArrRet(i, 0) = i
            ArrRet(i, 1) = PropertyName
            ArrRet(i, 2) = PropertyValue

        End If
    Next
   ParseEmailHeader = ArrRet
End Function
```